# Why $1\frac{1}{2}\ne \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: notation, math-history

Why mathematicians have chosen notation such that in algebra $1\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$ but $x\frac{y}{z}=\frac{xy}{z}$, instead of $x\frac{y}{z}=\frac{xz+y}{z}$?

Comment: Expressions like $1\frac{1}{2}$ are very seldom used in mathematics. One is taught about them in school because they are used in non-mathematical writing.

Comment: Because each is useful in different contexts. The mixed number notation is convenient in, say, cooking, where fractional measurements must be made by hand. The algebraic multiplication notation is convenient for serious mathematics, which tends to include more symbolic manipulation.

Comment: $12$ is not same as $1*2$, similarly  $1 \frac{1}{2}$ is not same as $1*\frac{1}{2}$ - the difference becomes clear based on context somehow

Comment: *Why ?* - To confuse people.

Comment: To my eye, $1\frac{1}{2}$ as rendered here looks wrong because $1$ is not the same height as $\frac{1}{2}$. But I would agree that it is most useful outside mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1\frac12=1+\frac12$$ and not $$1\cdot\frac12$$

Comment: Yes but is there any reason why there is a plus between numbers but a multiplication between letters?

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question of why the same notation is used differently in two cases.

Comment: The likely reason for the notation is that mixed fractions are used in all sorts of basic business transactions and for abbreviating phrases like "one and a half" in other contexts (e.g. recipes), and so they developed as a way to express useful quantities in writing. Mixed fractions are not used much in the context of mathematics itself, even at relatively low levels such as calculus.